# Taylor series in Maple for root of $x=e^{a\frac{\ln(1+b/x)}{\ln(1+b/x)+c}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, matlab, maple, mathematica

> I want to find the Taylor series for the following function in Maple:
>
> Root of 
>   $$x=\large e^{a\cdot \dfrac{\ln\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)}{\ln\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)+c}}$$ when $a,b,c>0$

I use: series(RootOf(m = exp(a*ln(1+b/x)/(ln(1+b/x)+c)), m), a)

Maple returns:

\begin{align}
\label{eq:1} 1+\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{b+x}{x}\right) }{\ln\left(\dfrac{b+x}{x}\right)+c}a+\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{b+x}{x}\right)^2 }{2\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{b+x}{x}\right)+c\right)^2}a^2+\cdots+O(a^6)
\end{align}

[fourth to sixth terms are dropped for brevity]

As you see, the parameter $x$ appears again which is not what we want. Do you know how I can solve this?

If **MAPLE** does not work, let me know if you can do this in **MATLAB** or **MATHEMATICA**

Second question, do you know how I can convert the output style of MAPLE to Latex? The output I got from MAPLE was originally different (see below) and it took me some time to convert it to a beautiful form written above.

1+a*ln((b+x)/x)/(ln((b+x)/x)+c)+(1/2)*ln((b+x)/x)^2*a^2/(ln((b+x)/x)+c)^2+(1/6)*ln((b+x)/x)^3*a^3/(ln((b+x)/x)+c)^3+(1/24)*ln((b+x)/x)^4*a^4/(ln((b+x)/x)+c)^4+(1/120)*ln((b+x)/x)^5*a^5/(ln((b+x)/x)+c)^5+O(a^6)

Comment: Yeah, doubt its solvable like that.  One a brighter note, one can attempt fixed-point iteration, though I'm unsure if it converges.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Can you talk about it more?

Comment: Fixed point is simple.  As an example, consider trying to solve $x=\sqrt 3$.  We know that $x^2=3$, or $2x^2=3+x^2$, or $x=\frac{3+x^2}{2x}$.  This nifty formula can be tied with fixed point method.  We know that $\sqrt3\approx\sqrt4=2$, so we start with $2$.$$x_0=2\\x_1=\frac{3+2^2}{2\cdot2}=\frac74\\x_2=\frac{3+(x_1)^2}{2x_1}=\frac{97}{56}\approx1.73214\\\vdots\\\sqrt3=1.73205$$So just repeatedly apply the formula until you are satisfied.  For this problem, $x_{n+1}=e^{f(x_n)}$ where $f$ is your exponent.

Comment: Is the ultimate goal to compute a value of $x$ solving this equation in terms of $a, b, c$? Or is the Taylor expansion of $x$ in terms of $a$ really what you are looking for?

Comment: @TobErnack Well, what I really wanted was to find a formula for $x$ with respect to parameters $a,b,c$.  Since I couldn't solve it for $x$, I wanted to find the series for $x$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Or maybe it should be like this: `series(RootOf(x = exp(a*ln(1+b/x)/(ln(1+b/x)+c)), x), a)`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you changed the x to and m, it should be:

```
series(RootOf(x = exp(a*ln(1+b/x)/(ln(1+b/x)+c)), x), a);
```

You can use the `latex()` command to produce latex markup of a Maple expression.  I got the following from:

```
latex(series(RootOf(x = exp(a*ln(1+b/x)/(ln(1+b/x)+c)), x), a, 2));
```

$$1+{\frac {\ln  \left( b+1 \right) }{\ln  \left( b+1 \right) +c}}a+{
\frac {\ln  \left( b+1 \right)  \left(  \left( \ln  \left( b+1
 \right)  \right) ^{2}b+\ln  \left( b+1 \right) bc+ \left( \ln 
 \left( b+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}+\ln  \left( b+1 \right) c-2\,bc
 \right) }{2\, \left( \ln  \left( b+1 \right) +c \right) ^{3} \left( b
+1 \right) }}{a}^{2}+O \left( {a}^{3} \right)$$